# Counter word for prepackaged instant ramen

Tags: word-choice, counters, food

What would be the most adequate counter word for this type of instant noodles? 
Like '1 package of ramen'.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since these come in 'bags' rather than in cups, you can use the 袋{ふくろ} counter.

> インスタントラーメン一袋{ひとふくろ}

Comment: 袋 sounds great, I'll check.

Comment: 一{ひと}パック is also quite common.

Comment: @broccoliforest in my opinion that could be posted as another answer. I could just edit it into mine but I don't want to steal your credit!

Comment: OK, Thank you. I seek to make an answer, though I don't seem to have other words to add :)